# VLOOKUP formula... is this the right formula for what I am trying to accomplish?

Tags: excel

I want to lookup a specific date from cell `E2` within a list of dates (column `A`) and return the corresponding value in column `B` from the matching date values ***IF*** column `D` does not equal `"NA"`. I want the column of revised dates (**RevDate** column) to coincide with the specific **Q** measurement when the **tss** data was `<> "NA"`.  This will give me the specific **Q** value when **tss** was measured on a specific date.

Formulas I have tried in Excel:

```
=IF(D2<>"NA",VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$D$445196,4,FALSE),0)
=IF(VLOOKUP(E2,A$2:D$445196,2,FALSE)="NA","",)
```

I feel I am close.... maybe????

[image: Example Screen Shot]

Comment: Please post data as text table so that we can copy paste to our excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have per date in `A` column just a single value in column `D` that is not `NA`(as per your sample), then you can use `FILTER`. `VLOKUP` will return the first match, and this is not what you want.

```
=FILTER($B$2:$B$445196, ($D$2:$D$445196<>"NA") * ($A$2:$A$445196=E2))
```

In case `FILTER` returns multiple rows, you would need to concatenate the result as follow:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER($B$2:$B$445196, ($D$2:$D$445196<>"NA") 
 * ($A$2:$A$445196=E2), "Not Found"))
```

Added also not found condition (if not it returns `#N/A`), that covers the case of `10/3/2010` for example. You can replace with an empty string as per in your second formula.

Comment: In case of multiple values return by `FILTER()` need use `TEXTJOIN()` otherwise filter will give spill error.

Comment: Exactly, but according to the input sample such case doesn't happen. I will clarify it. Thanks